# Patterns to segregate Models and DbContext on ASP.NET Core microservices

Tags: design-patterns, asp.net-core, .net-core, microservices, ef-core-2.0

I'm trying to make my services to deploy individually without depending on each other.

All services will be using the same SQL database using EF Core (same DbContext).

I'm using a separate project (MyServices.Data) that has all my models and the DbContext, but I'm really dependent on this and if there is any change on this Data project, all services needs to be redeployed.

Is there any pattern/approach to this situation so I can have my project not dependant on it?

Comment: yeah, you just have to use one database and one data project per service. the technology does not matter - that't one of main principles of microservices - **DON'T SHARE DATABASE!**

Comment: @PavelAgarkov do you have any references to this affirmation? but, supposing I go this way (which seems ok), several of my services need to check on user-related data. Correct approach would be to create also a User service for checking these data?

Comment: yes, you need an api for that. For .net-cor there is identity server 4 v2. You can start from watching youtube videos from NDC Conf / GOTO conf / QCon and so on. They have even special sections for microservices - there you can find all the patterns and books to learn next

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good start to read up on patterns & best practices:

[Web Applications with ASP.NET Core Architecture and Patterns guidance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/update-web-applications-with-asp-net-core-architecture-and-patterns-guidance-updated-for-asp-net-core-2/)

Although not recommended you can have your microservies share one database. If you go that route each MS should have their own scheme and their own migration history table. This is easily done using EF Core. As pointed out already, each MS should have their own data models and they can not share tables, even if they might contain almost identical data.

Microservices should not share data models.